# Code Completion in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, completion

I'm new using Code::Blocks (I'm using it under Ubuntu 16) and I'm experiencing a rare problem.

When using namespaces like:

```
using namespace std;
```

code completion doesn't show anything.

Example:

`stri` -> Here should show something and it doesn't

but if I do

`std::str` -> then it works

I'm using version 16.01 of Code::Blocks.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: isnt the fix is obvious? dont use `using namespace std;`

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @tobi303 mmmm the case of std was to put an easy example, but if I have to write every time ci::gl::(whatever) is very anoying... so is not obvious no?? and its better to use using namespace ci::gl;